# Why DataFrame correlation shows those results

Tags: python, pandas

Given a DataFrame, I try to select from several tries (represented as columns) the one(s) that fit the best the `target` column.

```
import pandas as pd  # tried with pandas 0.22 and pandas 0.20

data = {0.1: {10000.0: 1.1417023723316702,
       20000.0: 1.675669860738065,
       30000.0: 2.1391047345794565,
       40000.0: 2.588884897140648},
 0.3: {10000.0: 3.4251071169950102,
       20000.0: 5.027009582214195,
       30000.0: 6.4173142037383695,
       40000.0: 7.766654691421943},
 0.5: {10000.0: 5.708511861658351,
       20000.0: 8.378349303690324,
       30000.0: 10.695523672897282,
       40000.0: 12.94442448570324},
 0.7: {10000.0: 7.99191660632169,
       20000.0: 11.729689025166454,
       30000.0: 14.973733142056194,
       40000.0: 18.122194279984534},
 0.9: {10000.0: 10.275321350985031,
       20000.0: 15.081028746642584,
       30000.0: 19.25194261121511,
       40000.0: 23.29996407426583},
 'target': {10000.0: 8.95547589186585,
            20000.0: 12.664955463781974,
            30000.0: 15.511339250669858,
            40000.0: 17.9109517837317}}

values = pd.DataFrame(data)

values
Out[4]: 
              0.1       0.3        0.5        0.7        0.9     target
10000.0  1.141702  3.425107   5.708512   7.991917  10.275321   8.955476
20000.0  1.675670  5.027010   8.378349  11.729689  15.081029  12.664955
30000.0  2.139105  6.417314  10.695524  14.973733  19.251943  15.511339
40000.0  2.588885  7.766655  12.944424  18.122194  23.299964  17.910952
```

My plan was to use  Pandas [DataFrame.corr()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) to get a quick hint. However, the results I get are not that use full, since all the values for `target` vs. try equals to 1.

What is wrong with this approach:

```
values.corr()
Out[5]: 
             0.1       0.3       0.5       0.7       0.9    target
0.1     1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  0.998252
0.3     1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  0.998252
0.5     1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  0.998252
0.7     1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  0.998252
0.9     1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  0.998252
target  0.998252  0.998252  0.998252  0.998252  0.998252  1.000000
```

Comment: All your columns are correlated with the target and with each other. Use any one of them - it doesn't matter.

Comment: well, I just try to mimic https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html?highlight=correlation#correlation, where all the columns are correlated against all the other ones (aka "pairwise correlation")

Comment: But there the data was random, and by you it's really not.